# Permission denied while creating image from scratch

Tags: docker

Trying to create image from scratch according [manual](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/#create-a-full-image-using-tar).

Command below did needed job
$ sudo debootstrap xenial xenial > /dev/null

Tried to create image:
$ sudo tar -C xenial -c . | docker import - xenial

Got error:

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.35/images/create?fromSrc=-&message=&repo=xenial&tag=: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

How to fix that?

Comment: http issue ... docker login ..... needed?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo tar -C xenial -c . | sudo docker import - xenial`

Please note the sudo after the pipe.